# python how to code one line if else with a None value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use one line to code the logic :

if the user email is None then user email equal to 'test@abc.com'.

I have tried:

```
user_email = 'test@abc.com' if user_email is None
```

Error:

```
             if user_email is None
                                 ^
       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any friend can help ?

Comment: ```
Though it had been delayed for several years by disagreements over syntax, an operator for a conditional expression in Python was approved as Python Enhancement Proposal 308 and was added to the 2.5 release in September 2006. Python's conditional operator differs from the common ?: operator in the order of its operands. The general form is:

result = x if a > b else y

This form invites considering x as the normal value and y as an exceptional case.
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python

Comment: ```user_email = 'test@abc.com' if user_email is None else user_email```

Answer (score -2):

```
if len(email) == 0: email = "test@abc.com"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: One line not 2 line

Comment: Also this fails if `user_email is None`